# MIPS: read character without echo

Tags: mips, system-calls, mars-simulator

I'm using MARS. Is it possible to read a character from console without echo? Like `int 21h / 08h` in DOS. Or is there a way to hack it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use MMIO to poll the keyboard in SPIM/MARS:

```
li $t0,0xffff0000          # ffff0000 = Receiver (keyboard) control 
wait_for_key:
    lw   $t1,($t0)  
    andi $t1,$t1,0x0001 # Check the "ready" bit
    beq  $t1,$0,wait_for_key
    lw   $v0,4($t0)     # ffff0004 = Receiver data
```

Comment: This does work! However I must use the keyboard simulator to write to the register.